# HashCode for Generic objects in Java

Tags: java, hashcode

I understand the idea of hashCode and why it's needed. However I'm confused about how hashCode is calculated for a Generic object. So here's my questions. If I've a String, I'd probably use the following function to calculate the hashCode,

```
int hash = 7;
for (int i = 0; i < strlen; i++) {
    hash = hash*31 + charAt(i);
}
```

But say I've the following object,

```
class Node<K, V> {

        private K key;
        private V value;
        private Node<K, V> next;
}
```

My IDE generates an automated hashCode function for this,

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
      int result = key != null ? key.hashCode() : 0;
      result = 31 * result + (value != null ? value.hashCode() : 0);
      result = 31 * result + (next != null ? next.hashCode() : 0);
      return result;
}
```

My questions is since Key and Value are generic,what does `key.hashCode()` do?
How does this method work?

Comment: `key.hashCode()` uses polymorphism to call whatever implementation you gave the class which implements `key`

Comment: There's no such thing as a generic object. There are generic *types*, which can be used to reference some particular type of object, which will invariably have a `hashCode()` method, as every object is an instance of `Object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`K` and `V` are the parametrized types of your `Node` object.

As such, `hashCode` will be invoked on the actual types.

For instance a `Node<String, Integer>` will have `String#hashCode` and `Integer#hashCode` invoked respectively.

If you're parametrizing it with custom objects, either their own implementation of `hashCode` or their parent's implementation of `hashCode` will be invoked, up to `Object#hashCode`, which is a native (i.e. platform-dependent) implementation.

Comment: If I got this right, you mean String and Integer objects have their own hashCode methods which will be called based on what concrete types the class is instantiated with?

Comment: @CodeMonkey **yes**, as alamar says. You can look up the source for `String` or `Integer` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Java has a default `Object.hashCode()` implementation.

> As much as is reasonably practical, the `hashCode` method defined by class `Object` does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the Java programming language.)

If `hashCode()` is overriden in concrete classes of K and V, then exact overriding method will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Java's `Object` class has a `.hashCode()` method (albeit one based on the reference, so not often one you want to use.) `key.hashCode()` is thus guaranteed to exist, and can be dispatched correctly no matter what the specific type of this generic is. It will either use `Object`'s '.hashCode()` implementation, or a more specific one if available.